# Running js function from button and displaying

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I have made a function called "compare" and want to run it from a button with the id "start"

```
<input type="button" id="start" onClick="compare(userChoice, computerChoice)" value="Start">
```

but when it's pressed the function does not load, also I tried to display it in this

```
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

but the problem with it is that it starts as the page loads

```js
<script>

        var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
 computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
 computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
 computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
  if(choice1 === choice2){
   return "The result is a tie!"
  }
  else if(choice1 === "rock"){
   if(choice2 === "scissors"){
    return "rock wins";
   }
   else{
    return "paper wins"
   }
  }
  
  
  else if(choice1 === "paper"){
   if(choice2 === "rock"){
    return "paper wins";
   }
   else{
    return "scissors wins"
   }
  }
  
  
  
  
  
   else if(choice1 === "scissors"){
   if(choice2 === "paper"){
    return "scissors wins";
   }
   else{
    return "rock wins"
   }
  }
  
};
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = userChoice;
document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML = computerChoice;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice) ;

</script>
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: This has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function compare returns a string, so, calling it from onclick will result in nothing happening, you haven't specified what you want to do with the return of the function

rather than all your "returns" in that function, you could replace them with

```
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =
```

a better way would be something like

```
var compare = function() {
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    var check = function () {
        if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
            return "The result is a tie!"
        } else if (userChoice === "rock") {
            if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
                return "rock wins";
            } else {
                return "paper wins"
            }
        } else if (userChoice === "paper") {
            if (computerChoice === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins"
            }
        } else if (userChoice === "scissors") {
            if (computerChoice === "paper") {
                return "scissors wins";
            } else {
                return "rock wins"
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = check();
};
```

or even

```
var compare = function() {
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = function () {
        if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
            return "The result is a tie!"
        } else if (userChoice === "rock") {
            if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
                return "rock wins";
            } else {
                return "paper wins"
            }
        } else if (userChoice === "paper") {
            if (computerChoice === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins"
            }
        } else if (userChoice === "scissors") {
            if (computerChoice === "paper") {
                return "scissors wins";
            } else {
                return "rock wins"
            }
        }
    }(); // IIEF
};
```

(code edited based on comment question)

in both cases you can change the button to

```
<input type="button" id="start" onClick="compare()" value="Start"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, do you know how to start it?

Comment: "start it" ??? doesn't `<input type="button" id="start" onClick="compare(userChoice, computerChoice)" value="Start">` work for you?

Comment: No it doesn't do anything also I changed the code from return to 
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =

Comment: is there a way to make the prompt pop up after the button is pressed?

Comment: yes, but that wasn't in your question - see edited code for an answer to this new question

Comment: I deliberately didn't put the code in where EVERY return is replaced by the long winded `document.getElementById` way of achieving what you want. If that's how you want to do it, you should be able to guess where the additional code I just added should go in your version of the function

Comment: in the answer - the first 10 or so lines in the compare functions

Comment: I changed it but still when I click the button the prompt does not appear.

Comment: you'll see that the compare function no longer needs arguments, in the comparisons in the inner function are `userChoice vs computerChoice`, rather than the now deleted arguments `choice1 vs choice2` - also not the changes to the `onclick` - while the old version would work, no need to keep potentially confusing arguments where they are not needed

Comment: you've taken bits and pieces from the two different solutions plus the general first option, put them all together to create frankenstein monster of code - compare what you did on the fiddle with this edit http://jsfiddle.net/duudwrvs/1/